# saving settings of checkbox in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

i have a form with some checkboxes on it i want to save those settings.

how can i save the settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you loathe the REGISTRY, you can have a CONFIG file (essentially XML) with KEY / VALUE pairs.

The REGISTRY can be cumbersome on so many levels including remembering to REMOVE any settings you may have saved when you UNINSTALL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SaveSetting` function for that, to retrieve you can use `GetSetting` function. **[See this fore more info.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=232113)**

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your settings into a class, then serialize the class to an xml file using the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).